# Run two ffmpeg commands one after another

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I need to run two `ffmpeg` commands, one after the other i.e., wait until the first command has finished, and then run the second command. The first command is

```
ffmpeg -threads 8 -i D:\imagesequence\dpx\brn_055.%04d.dpx D:\imagesequence\dpx\test2.mov
```

and the second is

```
ffmpeg -i D:/imagesequence/background.jpg -vf "movie='D\:/imagesequence/dpx/thumbnail.jpg' [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/3 [out]" D:/imagesequence/dpx/final_with_text_mod_04.jpg
```

What is the best way to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: Have you read python's subprocess.call ? (Also, you actually don't have 8 cores. It might be faster using 4 threads and disabling hyperthreading. )

Comment: can u expound on that. 8 cores, 4 threads, hyperthreading. is there a place where i can find information on this

Comment: Sorry, I take back my comment. The impact of hyperthreading on a program is entirely dependent on the program itself. Google "ffmpeg hyperthreading" to find out more. Hyperthreading (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) is basically where you have two logical cores for each physical core. It might look as if you have 8 cores, but the workload is split between 4 physical cores. Unless of course, you actually have 8 physical cores, e.g. some Xeon or AMD processors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything more than calling 2 times a `ffmpeg` command with `subprocess` python module, this is already the default behaviour

```
import subprocess

execstr1 = 'ffmpeg -x -y -z ...'
execstr2 = 'ffmpeg -a -b -c ...'

out1 = subprocess.check_output(execstr1, shell=True)

out2 = subprocess.check_output(execstr2, shell=True)
```

Comment: `a = subprocess.check_call(["ffmpeg", "-threads", "8", "-i", "D:/imagesequence/background.jpg", "-vf", "movie='D\:/imagesequence/dpx/......[out]", "D:/imagesequence/dpx/brn_055.0000.dpx"],shell=True)  if (a == 0):
 b = subprocess.check_call(["ffmpeg", "-threads", "8", "-i", "D:/imagesequence/dpx/brn_055.%04d.dpx", "-vf", "drawtext=f..........tcolor=Yellow", "D:/imagesequence/dpx/test2.mov"],shell=True)`             I need to run one after another. is it possible. I had to trim the command coz of limited space